# Regex - pattern for 2 string enclosed by curly braces and separated by period

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this string:

"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, {{foo.name}} consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. {{bar.address}} Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, {{dummy.company}} pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. "

I need to extract the strings (foo.name, bar.address, dummy.company) enclosed in double curly braces and composed of 2 substring separated by a period. How can I do this using regex?

Still a beginner in regex and tried /[a-z].[a-z]/ but haven't got the right match.

Comment: Depending on your application, using a template engine instead of a custom regex might be better. http://handlebarsjs.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using regexp101.com:

```
$re = '/({{.*?}})/';
$str = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, {{foo.name}} consectetuer adipiscing elit.
Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. {{bar.address}} Aenean massa. Cum sociis 
natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. 
Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, {{dummy.company}} pellentesque eu, pretium 
quis, sem.';

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);

// Print the entire match result
var_dump($matches);
```

oops that is php - the JavaScript is:

```
const regex = /({{.*?}})/g;
const str = `Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, {{foo.name}} consectetuer adipiscing elit. 
Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. {{bar.address}} Aenean massa. Cum sociis 
natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. 
Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, {{dummy.company}} pellentesque eu, pretium 
quis, sem. `;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }

    // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
    m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
        console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
    });
}
```